# How does a NoneType function work?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

In order to create an `update_score` function for a game I am developing a function that returns `NoneType`. I was searching some information about this kind of function in Python 3 and as far as I know what I was supposed to do is try to create it without printing, but what does it really mean to return a `NoneType`?

I tried to code this function by using other function called `word_score` which seems to work properly but I got stuck in the `update_score` function.

```
def word_score(word):
    """ (str) -> int

    Return the point value the word earns.

    Word length: < 3: 0 points
                 3-6: 1 point per character for all characters in word
                 7-9: 2 points per character for all characters in word
                 10+: 3 points per character for all characters in word

    >>> word_score('DRUDGERY')
    16
    >>> word_score('PEN')
    3
    >>> word_score('GRANDMOTHER')
    33
    """
    if len(word) < 3:
        return 0
    elif len(word) in range(3,7):
        return len(word)
    elif len(word) in range(7, 10):
        return len(word)* 2
    elif len(word) >= 10:
        return len(word) * 3



    return word_score


def update_score(player_info, word):
    """ ([str, int] list, str) -> NoneType

    player_info is a list with the player's name and score. Update player_info
    by adding the point value word earns to the player's score.

    >>> update_score(['Jonathan', 4], 'ANT')
    """

    return update_score(['player_info', word_score], 'word')
```

Do you see something strange in this one?

Comment: A `NoneType` function is a simply a function that doesn't explicitly return anything (or explicitly does `return None`).

Comment: should I delete that return and keep the rest them?

Comment: The rest doesn't seem that useful either.

Comment: Could you give a hint in order to create it properly? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NoneType` function is one that doesn't explicitly return anything or one that explicitly returns `None` when it terminates. An important aspect of this is that the function *returns*. The `update_score()` in the code in your question unconditionally calls itself thus creating an infinite loop that doesn't terminate until an exception that stops the entire script occurs.

So you don't want to do that. Here's a modified version of `update_score()` that instead just updates the value in the list it was passed, **in-place**, and then returns it. Returning it (or anything else) like that isn't strictly necessary since `list`s are mutable sequences—so you might not need the `return player_info` I have at the end (that technically was keeping it from being `NoneType` function).

Note that I also optimized the `word_score()` function a bit.

```
def word_score(word):
    """ (str) -> int

    Return the point value the word earns.

    Word length: < 3: 0 points
                 3-6: 1 point per character for all characters in word
                 7-9: 2 points per character for all characters in word
                 10+: 3 points per character for all characters in word

    >>> word_score('DRUDGERY')
    16
    >>> word_score('PEN')
    3
    >>> word_score('GRANDMOTHER')
    33
    """
    word_len = len(word)
    if word_len < 3:
        return 0
    elif word_len <= 6:
        return word_len
    elif word_len <= 9:
        return word_len * 2
    else: # word_len >= 10
        return word_len * 3

def update_score(player_info, word):
    """ ([str, int] list, str) -> [str, int] list

    player_info is a list with the player's name and score. Update player_info
    by adding the point value word earns to the player's score.

    >>> update_score(['Jonathan', 4], 'ANT')
    ['Jonathan', 7]
    """
    player_info[1] += word_score(word)
    return player_info

print(update_score(['Jonathan', 4], 'ANT'))  # -> ['Jonathan', 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

`update_score` always calls itself, so never gets to return.